# Excel - Sorting Data Pulled From Another Sheet

Tags: excel, sorting, filter, datatables

I have two worksheets in a workbook I'm designing for teachers to use next year.

One worksheet is where they enter student information and one that is a general student roster. Theres alot more data on the student information (SI) sheet, so it makes sense for them to start there. The roster sheet is automatically generated based on the data entry into the SI and is moreso used in our office. The cells in the roster table are just coded as =Table13[@[Last Name]] so it pulls the info over essentially in real time.

- Teacher enters info on SI
- Info from SI auto populates into a table on Roster.

I can filter without an issue on the roster sheet, but I can't do any sorting there and thats the problem. If I want to list the students alphabetically on the roster, I have to go into the SI sheet and alphabetize there.

Is there any way to work around this? The excel filter also prompts with "sort smallest to largest" rather than A to Z, so I'm thinking its reading these cells as numbers?

Comment: Is there a reason for the instant update?  If not, create a macro which populates the Roster sheet by scanning the Student Information sheet.  Connect the macro to a button on the Roster sheet that says "update".

Other ideas to think about: VLOOKUP() & Pivot Tables

Comment: ...Actually, I think there is an option in Pivot Tables which allows sorting.  Question: Will every record on the Student Information (SI) sheet show up on the Roster (R) sheet (you already said not every field on the SI sheet will show up in the R sheet)?

Comment: No - I'm only pulling a half dozen or so records from the SI sheet into the roster. But if I had to pull them all, I could just hide those columns and it wouldnt be a problem.

So you think the roster should be setup as a pivot table?

Comment: Not sure if you can hide records from a Pivot Table.

Answer (score 1):

***To reduce the number of records, reduce the number of fields, and place records in the desired order:***

Consider using Excel [Pivot Tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).  When creating the Pivot Table select only records with the desired data and the fields to be displayed in the final presentation.  Also select to Sort the data.

Comment: I'm in a rush but believe these 2 steps satisfy your needs to reduce the number of records, reduce the number of fields and sort the resulting records automatically.  Add a comment if the answer is not clear.

Comment: ...should add that you may not need VLOOKUP if you can devise a way to for the Pivot Table to eliminate records.  Actually, I would try that approach.  Yep, going to change my answer.

Comment: appreciate your help, will give it a try

Comment: You may have to consider how you are entering data into the SI sheet in order to make it possible to use Pivot Tables.  Nothing new here.  It's about making good decisions.  Like it's better to separate first and last names into their own fields so that you can sort on the last names.

Comment: Maybe I'm limited in my use of pivot tables, but as I know it, I don't see how this helps me.  All I want to do is mirror/replicate the data from one sheet to another but with the ability to sort it on the second sheet. A pivot table can do this?

Comment: i didnt intend for this to sound as unappreciative as it did - apologies!

Comment: You can use the easier VLOOKUP.  But I don't think VLOOKUP will do any sorting for you.  It would be best if the source table was sorted first if you are going to use VLOOKUP.  Pivot Tables does offer sorting.  And Pivot tables should be able to trim data by both removing records (lines) and fields (columns).  If you add about half a dozen example lines (fake names) to your question I might be able to edit my question to make it clearer despite the question being closed / closing.

Comment: BTW, [Excel questions are likely best suited for the Super User stackexchange web site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155487/if-i-had-a-question-with-excel-which-site-would-i-use).  Maybe someone will migrate this question to that site.